# Find meeting time with room

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm facing a problem with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I'm trying to find an available time slot between my attendees, me and the meeting room.

```
 {
 "attendees": [
     {
         "emailAddress": {
             "address": "madreww@mycompany.com"
         },
         "type": "Required"
     }
 ],
 "timeConstraint": {
     "timeslots": [
         {
             "start": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T12:00:00.000Z",
                 "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
             },
             "end": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T15:00:00.000Z",
                 "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
             }
         }
     ]
 },
 "locationConstraint": {
     "isRequired": "true",
     "suggestLocation": "false",
     "locations": [
         {
             "locationEmailAddress": "room-accueil@mycompany.com"
         }
     ]
 },
 "meetingDuration": "PT1H"
 }
```

But the problem if the room "room-accueil@mycompany.com" is booked from 12AM TO 1PM and the response display this available time slot without taking in account the booked room.

Do you have a idea why? And how I can check with this method, if attendees, organizer and the meeting room are all available in a meeting slot time?

Response:

```
{
 "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
 "emptySuggestionsReason": "",
 "meetingTimeSuggestions": [
     {
         "confidence": 100,
         "organizerAvailability": "free",
         "attendeeAvailability": [
             {
                 "availability": "free",
                 "attendee": {
                     "emailAddress": {
                         "address": "madreww@mycompany.com"
                     }
                 }
             }
         ],
         "locations": [
             {
                 "locationEmailAddress": "room-accueil@mycompany.com",
                 "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
             }
         ],
         "meetingTimeSlot": {
             "start": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T12:00:00.0000000",
                 "timeZone": "UTC"
             },
             "end": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T13:00:00.0000000",
                 "timeZone": "UTC"
             }
         }
     },
     {
         "confidence": 100,
         "organizerAvailability": "free",
         "attendeeAvailability": [
             {
                 "availability": "tentative",
                 "attendee": {
                     "emailAddress": {
                         "address": "madreww@mycompany.com"
                     }
                 }
             }
         ],
         "locations": [
             {
                 "locationEmailAddress": "room-accueil@mycompany.com",
                 "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
             }
         ],
         "meetingTimeSlot": {
             "start": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T13:00:00.0000000",
                 "timeZone": "UTC"
             },
             "end": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T14:00:00.0000000",
                 "timeZone": "UTC"
             }
         }
     },
     {
         "confidence": 100,
         "organizerAvailability": "free",
         "attendeeAvailability": [
             {
                 "availability": "free",
                 "attendee": {
                     "emailAddress": {
                         "address": "madreww@mycompany.com"
                     }
                 }
             }
         ],
         "locations": [
             {
                 "locationEmailAddress": "room-accueil@mycompany.com",
                 "locationType": "conferenceRoom"
             }
         ],
         "meetingTimeSlot": {
             "start": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T14:00:00.0000000",
                 "timeZone": "UTC"
             },
             "end": {
                 "dateTime": "2023-01-11T15:00:00.0000000",
                 "timeZone": "UTC"
             }
         }
     }
 ]
 }
```

But If I use the room in attendees, the room seems to be always booked and always busy

[image]

Comment: are there any time zone differences to consider?

Comment: @blurfus no all are in the same Timezone

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the meeting room as an attendee with type `resource`.  Example:

```json
{
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "madreww@mycompany.com"
      },
      "type": "required"
    },
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "room-accueil@mycompany.com"
      },
      "type": "resource"
    }
  ],
  "timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2023-01-11T12:00:00.000Z",
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2023-01-11T15:00:00.000Z",
          "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "locationConstraint": {
    "isRequired": "true",
    "suggestLocation": "false",
    "locations": [
      {
        "locationEmailAddress": "room-accueil@mycompany.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H"
}
```